# How to set Formik form erros from redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, formik

I am working on pretty standard React/Redux/Redux-Saga style app.

I have Login form what using Formik. Inside `onSubmit` I have action call `loginUser()`. Saga take care of API call side effect and if there is error saga dispatch `LOGIN_USER_ERROR` action what update store with this error.

So inside my Login component I now have mapped error prop from store saying for example `Network error`.

My question is pretty simple: How to update Formik form after error prop is updated? Same question goes for `un-general` server errrors like `{'username': 'Already exists'}`. I need to show error feedback under input like when I was validating on client side before call.

Hope you will understand my problem. I think its understadable without demo code, but I can provide it if you don't understand me.

Answer (score 1):

Formik 2.x has [`initialErrors` prop](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/docs/api/formik.md#initialerrors-formikerrorsvalues), but in the meantime / current stable version I'd use the imperative [`setErrors`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#seterrors-fields-field-string-string-void)